# how to conver a m4v(mpeg) codec raw video to a mp4 file which can be played?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, m4v

I uses the following command that can extract the mpeg4 raw video file：

```
ffmpeg -i D:\mp4v-mp4\test\360.mov -vcodec copy -an -f rawvideo D:\mp4v-mp4\test\360CmdSplit_std.dat
```

but how can I convert the rawvideo file back to a playable mp4 file.
I have tried the follow cmd, but failed:

```
ffmpeg -y -f m4v -i D:\mp4v-mp4\test\360CmdSplit_std1.dat -vcodec copy D:\mp4v-mp4\test\tmp360.mp4
```

Comment: Share full logs of both commands.

Comment: MP4 does not support raw video.

Answer (score -1):

the first cmd(extract the raw mp4v video) is success,logs:
D:\install\ffmpeg-4.3.1-essentials_build\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360(mp4v_aac).mov -vcodec copy -an -f rawvideo D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360mov_std.dat
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360(mp4v_aac).mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: qt
encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
Duration: 00:00:52.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 408 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 360x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 277 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
encoder         : Lavc58.22.101 mpeg4
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360mov_std.dat':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: qt
encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 360x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 277 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
encoder         : Lavc58.22.101 mpeg4
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1250 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1764kB time=00:00:52.08 bitrate= 277.5kbits/s speed=1.47e+03x
video:1764kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%

convert the rawvideo file back to a playable mp4 file,failed:

D:\install\ffmpeg-4.3.1-essentials_build\bin>ffmpeg -y -f m4v -i D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360mov_std.dat -vcodec copy D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\tmp360.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mpeg4 @ 00000214e53d47c0] time_increment_bits 0 is invalid in relation to the current bitstream, this is likely caused by a missing VOL header
[mpeg4 @ 00000214e53d47c0] time_increment_bits set to 5 bits, based on bitstream analysis
[mpeg4 @ 00000214e53d47c0] time_increment_bits 4 is invalid in relation to the current bitstream, this is likely caused by a missing VOL header
[mpeg4 @ 00000214e53d47c0] time_increment_bits set to 5 bits, based on bitstream analysis
[mpeg4 @ 00000214e53d47c0] looks like this file was encoded with (divx4/(old)xvid/opendivx) -> forcing low_delay flag
[m4v @ 00000214e53cab40] decoding for stream 0 failed
[m4v @ 00000214e53cab40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4, yuv420p): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, m4v, from 'D:\mp4v-mp4\MOV\360mov_std.dat':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
[mp4 @ 00000214e543a840] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Last message repeated 1 times

Comment: I think this is not the answer. You pasted the logs as answer which is not correct. Please read the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask